# How can I open .bak files from LibreOffice?

Tags: backup, libreoffice

LibreOffice creates `.bak` files, but I cannot open them.

Comment: Can you please add a little more information on what you tried to open this file? I would think the .bak might just be a renamed .od* file.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

Not automatically because the file type is not registered. You can, however, tell Libreoffice to open the .bak file.

1. From the file manager: right click the file, choose `Open with...`, and choose Libreoffice.
2. From Libreoffice itself: use the open dialog.

`.bak` files are located in the `backup` folder. The location of this folder can be found with Tools/Options/LibreOffice/Paths.